# How to create an Apex Trigger which calculates the number of students present in a group?

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code, apex

I want to create an apex trigger  on the Student object and calculate the number of students present in that group .

Answer (score 0):

if the group name or Id or any identifier is on the student object as a field you can query your SFDC Database to retrieve the students related to that group. It would be something like this:

```
List<Students__c> students = [SELECT Id FROM Student__c 
                              WHERE group__c = 'The group name or ID'];
```

Then you can use the students.size() method to get the number of students in that group.